# Data editing disabled in demo

Tags: codeigniter

I have an codeigniter web application, each time I try to make changes on the app im getting an error Data editing disabled in demo,what really could be the cause of this??

Have tried to make changes within the config file, but still no change.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What you have did so you are getting this error? Code sample?

Comment: for example, when i try to make changes as an admin, editing a users information and try to save the changes or even after registering a user and try and save the changes, thats when i get the error message Data editing disabled in demo..i hope its clear..